# PHP - Echo doing nothing in if statement

Tags: php

So this is the code I have so far, I have in mind that if the IPs match then echo a form with the details, if not echo an error message. but for some reason I can't get it to work

(need to add more details so just disregard this if you want) 
Basically the script fetches the client's IP, if the IP matches the one on file then display some credentials, if it doesn't then echo an error message or just echo some text into the text fields

```
   <?php


$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

?>
<?php
/**
 * Created by PhpStorm.
 * User: test
 * Date: 02/03/2017
 * Time: 03:15 ص
 */

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <link rel="icon" href="../../favicon.ico">

    <title>Login</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
      <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">


  </head>

  <body>

    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Password</a>
        </div>
        <div id="navbar" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="active"><a href="index.php">Passwords</a></li>


          </ul>
        </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
      </div>
    </nav>

    <div class="container">
             <form method="post" style="margin-top:100px;">
             <?php

       if($ip == "ip1" or "ip2"){

            $user = "someuser";
            $pass = "somepass";
            $pin = "somepin";
       echo "



            <div class=\"form-group\">
                <label for=\"exampleInputEmail1\">Username</label>
                <input type=\"email\" name=\"email\" class=\"form-control\" placeholder=\"Email\" value=\"$user \">
            </div>
            <div class=\"form-group\">
                <label for=\"exampleInputPassword1\">Password</label>
                <input type=\"text\" name=\"password\" class=\"form-control\" placeholder=\"Password\" value=\"$pass \">
            </div>
            <div class=\"form-group\">
                <label for=\"exampleInputPassword1\">Pin</label>
                <input type=\"text\" name=\"password\" class=\"form-control\" placeholder=\"Password\" value=\"$pin  \">
            </div>


       ";
       }
       else{
           echo "



            <div class=\"form-group\">
                <label for=\"exampleInputEmail1\">Username</label>
                <input type=\"email\" name=\"email\" class=\"form-control\" placeholder=\"Email\" value=\"  LOL \">
            </div>
            <div class=\"form-group\">
                <label for=\"exampleInputPassword1\">Password</label>
                <input type=\"text\" name=\"password\" class=\"form-control\" placeholder=\"Password\" value=\"  LOL \">
            </div>
            <div class=\"form-group\">
                <label for=\"exampleInputPassword1\">Pin</label>
                <input type=\"text\" name=\"password\" class=\"form-control\" placeholder=\"Password\" value=\"  LOL  \">
            </div>


       ";
       }

?>
</form>
    </div><!-- /.container -->


    <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript
    ================================================== -->
    <!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You're never going to get an IP address called either `ip1` or `ip2`. Also, the 'or' condition in PHP is `||`: `if($ip == "ip1" || $ip == "ip2"){`

Comment: I know I just made them ip1 or ip2 because I want to hide the original ips I have, they're just strings. @ObsidianAge

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
if($ip == "ip1" or $ip =="ip2"){

    $user = "someuser";
    $pass = "somepass";
    $pin = "somepin";
}
else
{
    $user = "LOL";
    $pass = "LOL";
    $pin = "LOL";
}
?>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Username</label>
                <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email" value="<?php echo $user; ?>">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Password</label>
                <input type="text" name="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" value="<?php echo $pass;?>">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Pin</label>
                <input type="text" name="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" value="<?php echo $pin;?>">
            </div>
```

or

```
<?php
if($ip == "ip1" or $ip =="ip2"){

    $user = "someuser";
    $pass = "somepass";
    $pin = "somepin";
}
else
{
    $user = "LOL";
    $pass = "LOL";
    $pin = "LOL";
}
echo '<div class="form-group">
                <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Username</label>
                <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email" value="'.$user.'">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Password</label>
                <input type="text" name="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" value="'.$pass.'">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Pin</label>
                <input type="text" name="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" value="'.$pin.'">
            </div>';
?>
```

Comment: That first one was literally one of the first revisions of my code, but I changed it because I thought it was wrong because the _if($ip == "ip1" or "ip2")_ isn't working, neither or/|| are working for "or" any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

1st you check the `$ip` value,

then try this format

```
if($ip=='ip1'){
//code here
}else if($ip=='ip2'){
//code here
}else{
//code here
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I totally forgot about else if

Answer (score 0):

I think if I were you I would use a native function like [in_array()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) to search in a list for the ip. If you have a bunch of `||`/`or` inside an `if` clause, it just get's ugly. Also, you can store ips in an `xml`, `json`, or other or external source like a database so you don't have to hardcode those stored values in the php file.

```
# Get the ip
$myIp = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
# In-php file list of ips
$listOfIps = array(
    '73.121.122.131',
    '213.22.132.11',
    '91.89.222.32'
);
# Check in the list for the user's ip
if(in_array($myIp,$listOfIps)) {
    // Do something here
}
```

To extract from an external file, it would look something like this. I have added some classes to make it a bit more human-readable:

**/ips.json**

```
["73.121.122.131","213.22.132.11","91.89.222.32"]
```

**/index.php**

```
class FileHandler
    {
        public function getIpList()
            {
                return json_decode(file_get_contents(__DIR__.'/ips.json'),true);
            }
    }

class Admin
    {
        private $FileHandler;

        public function __construct(\FileHandler $FileHandler)
            {
                $this->FileHandler = $FileHandler;
            }

        public function ipAllowed()
            {
                $ips = $this->FileHandler->getIpList();
                $ip  = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
                return in_array($ip,$ips);
            }
    }

$Admin  =  new Admin(new FileHandler());
if($Admin->ipAllowed()) {
    // Do special stuff here
}
else {
    // Do regular stuff
}
```

Comment: In all honesty I don't understand half of that, Care to explain?

Comment: If you have a list of ips that are "special", you use `in_array()` to search through the list. Let's say you have 10 ip addresses, doing it like others have suggested you would have to do a bunch of `if` or a big `switch` statement to check against the ips. That's a lot of hardcoding. If you have a list, you simply check that the current ip is in the list or not. That way you just add to the list or subtract from the list and you don't have to change any logic other than removing/adding to list.

Answer (score -1):

You can't use " to start your echo, then use them in the HTML. That creates an end of string.  Start your echo with ' and leave the double quotes as is.  Plus, Obsidian is correct about the "or" being ||.

Comment: I just updated the echo to start with ', but I didn't understand what you meant when you said _and leave the double quotes as is_

Comment: @common sense, actually that IS one of the several mistakes in that code. Maybe you should haveused the time you spent trolling my suggestions across SO to provide solutions for beginners.